# how to call iter_cb every iteration rather than every function evaluation?

Tags: lmfit

The minimize function in lmfit allows the specification of a function that is called every iteration with the keyword iter_cb. This function is called every function evaluation (so not every iteration in the least squares process). What I want to do is to call a function every iteration of the least squares process, after the parameters have been updated. For example, with 3 parameters, the residuals are evaluated 4 times to get 3 derivatives (4 function evaluations). After the parameters are updated I need to call a function before the next iteration (again 4 function evaluations). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is sort of "no" in that the underlying compiled code (scipy.optimize.leastsq uses MINPACK lmdif) makes no distinctions between calling the objective function to estimate the finite-difference jacobian.  In fact, it doesn't really count "iterations" of the estimated solution, but it does count number of function evaluations.

Also, it's not true that it will always do Nvars+1 function evaluations between updates of the values.  That is, there will often be a Nvars+1 evaluations, but it seems like it is sometimes Nvars+2 evaluations (or, rather 1 evaluation with rather unique values).

You could check "iter" (the count of the current function evaluation) that is passed into the iteration callback, and return quickly if the value isn't what you think it should be.  Or, you could check that the values have changed significantly since the last time the iteration-callback actually ran completely.